# Finding distinct values across multiple columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, distinct

the distinct function in R generates unique values within the same column. However, I would like to have unique values regardless which column the value appears in.

The sample data is shown below.

10A appears in the second row under var 1. It appears again in the third row, although it is in var 2 this time. I would like to remove the third row since at least one of the values (10A) is a duplicate.

In the 5th row, 10B have appeared in row 2, so I would also like to remove the 5th row as at least one of the values is a duplicate.

In the 6th row, although 7A has appeared before in rows 3 and 5, rows 3 and 5 will be removed, therefore 7A is not considered a duplicate and I would like to retain row 6.

Rows 7 and 8 have NA values. NA should not be considered as duplicate so rows 7 and 8 should be retained.

How do I do it in R?

Sample data

| var 1 | var 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5A | 5B |
| 10A | 10B |
| 7A | 10A |
| 6B | 5C |
| 10B | 7A |
| 10C | 7A |
| 99A | NA |
| NA | 99B |

Required Result

| var 1 | var 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 5A | 5B |
| 10A | 10B |
| 6B | 5C |
| 10C | 7A |
| 99A | NA |
| NA | 99B |

Comment: You're deleting value '7A' which is also unique...Why not bind all values and calculate distinct values?

Comment: My intention is to delete 7A too. Basically I would like to delete the whole row if any of the values in that row is a duplicate, even in a different column like in the case of 10A.

Answer (score 0):

If df has var1 & var2 variables and you wanting to maintain only var1 distinct values:

```
df |> 
  filter(!var2 %in% unique(var1))
```

Comment: I would like to maintain distinct values for var1 and var2, not just var1. As mentioned in my question, I would like to have unique values, regardless which column it appears in.

Comment: I asked you for value 7A and you answered you wanted to delete ir

Comment: Yes I want to delete it. Will your solution work if I have an additional row (5th row) in the sample data, where 10A is under var 1 and 7A under var 2? This additional row would also have to be removed in the required result.

Comment: Yes, it would be removed

Comment: Instead of my 5th row being 10A under var 1 and 7A under var 2, my 5th row is 10B under var 1 and 7A under var 2. Your solution will only give me 2 rows instead of 3 rows as shown in the required result.

Comment: Updated sample data and required result for better clarity.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

The data:

```r
dt <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "
'var1' 'var2'
'5A'   '5B2'  #1
'10A'  '10B'  #2
'7A'   '10A'  #3 - to be removed
'6B'   '5C'   #4
'10B'  '7A'   #5 - to be removed
'10C'  '7A'   #6
'99A'  'NA'   #7 - keep
'2A'   '3B'   #8
'NA'   '99B'   #9 - keep
'3A'   '11B'  #10")
```

Loop solution

```r
looper <- function(dt) {
  uniqstock <- unlist(na.omit(dt[1, 1:ncol(dt)]))
  rows2keep <- TRUE # which rows to keep
  
  # loop through data frame row by row
  for(r in 2:nrow(dt)) {
    rowdat <- na.omit(unlist(dt[r, ])) # na.omit to ignore NAs in row
    # Are *any* values in current row a duplicate to previous ones
    dupl <- any(rowdat %in% uniqstock)
    
    rows2keep <- c(rows2keep, !dupl)
    ### Set all values in current row to NA (in doing so removing them from future duplicate checks)
    if (!dupl)
      uniqstock <- c(uniqstock, rowdat)
  }
  
  dt[rows2keep,] # return but not before removing rows with NA
}
```

Applier solution

```r
applier <- function(dt) {
  uniqstock <- character()
  
  unqrows <- function(x) {
    # Are *any* values in current row a duplicate to previous ones
    dupl <- any(x %in% uniqstock)
    # Set all values in current row to NA (in doing so removing them from future duplicate checks)
    if (dupl) return(FALSE)
    
    uniqstock <<- c(uniqstock, na.omit(x))
    return(TRUE)
  }
  
  rows2keep <- apply(dt, 1, unqrows)
  dt[rows2keep,]
}
```

Recursion solution by @onyambu with small modifications to handle `NA`s correctly

```r
recursor <- function(dt) {
  relation <- function(dat){
    if(nrow(dat) == 1) dat
    else
    {
      # Include <- unlist(dat) %in% dat[1,]
      Include <- match(unlist(dat), dat[1,], nomatch = 0, incomparables = NA) > 0
      rbind(dat[1,],
            relation(dat[!tapply(Include, row(dat), sum),]))
    }
  }
  
  relation(dt)
}
```

**Benchmark**. Compare the solutions’ performance, since speed is important here:

```r
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  looper(dt), recursor(dt), applier(dt)#, check = "equivalent"
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>          expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
#>    looper(dt)  369.8  393.00  512.402  404.5  420.60  9094.1   100
#>  recursor(dt) 1408.5 1446.75 1725.944 1459.6 1492.75 16427.9   100
#>   applier(dt)  144.8  155.60  260.622  164.3  173.65  6143.0   100
```

---

Check the results of the solutions

```r
looper(dt)
#>    var1 var2
#> 1    5A  5B2
#> 2   10A  10B
#> 4    6B   5C
#> 6   10C   7A
#> 7   99A <NA>
#> 8    2A   3B
#> 9  <NA>  99B
#> 10   3A  11B
recursor(dt) # considers NA as duplicates
#>    var1 var2
#> 1    5A  5B2
#> 2   10A  10B
#> 4    6B   5C
#> 6   10C   7A
#> 7   99A <NA>
#> 8    2A   3B
#> 9  <NA>  99B
#> 10   3A  11B
applier(dt) # loses column labels
#>    var1 var2
#> 1    5A  5B2
#> 2   10A  10B
#> 4    6B   5C
#> 6   10C   7A
#> 7   99A <NA>
#> 8    2A   3B
#> 9  <NA>  99B
#> 10   3A  11B
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Jan, your solution works. However, in my updated sample data, it will not capture the last row (10C, 7A). Is there any workaround?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. See the update.

Comment: Thank you Jan for the update. I actually have 500k rows of data so your solution with the for loop is taking hours to run. Is there a vectorised solution that will take a shorter time to run?

Comment: I am not aware of a vectorised function that finds duplicates the way you need it. It might be possible to work with `apply` or a variation of it but that has limitations and won't guarantee higher speed. I may try something later today. In the meantime I replaced the `unlist` with a storage of previously found unique  values. That should make a big difference because we avoid a large operation on the upper part of the data frame that is repeated in every loop.

Comment: Thank you Jan for the revised code. It is still taking a long time though. Would like to highlight a separate issue. I have updated the sample data with NA values but apparently your solution will count NA as duplicate. Possible to revise your code to not count NA as duplicate?

Comment: @Anthony you only have 2 NA, include more. Ie include NA that has a duplicath

Comment: Thank you Jan for the comprehensive solutions which take care of the NAs. The applier’s speed is the fastest among the 3. I actually have a follow-up question on using the applier function after grouping data but I will post it separately.

Comment: I appreciate it. Leave me a note if you'd like me to take a look. ... by the way, the purpose of SO is to help as many people as possible. If the answer works for you, please accept it as solution so that others know it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use recursion to acomplish this:

```
relation <- function(dat){
  if(nrow(dat) == 1) dat
  else
   rbind(dat[1,],
      relation(dat[!tapply(unlist(dat) %in% dat[1,], row(dat), sum),]))
}

 relation(df)
  var.1 var.2
1    5A    5B
2   10A   10B
4    6B    5C
6   10C    7A
```

Comment: Thank you onyambu for the solution. May I know why do you use “dat[1,]” in lines 4 and 5 of your codes? It only refers to the first row of the dataframe?

Comment: @Anthony allow me ask. do you know what recursion is? If so then you can see that that dat[1,] loops over to the end of the data

Comment: @Anthony if this satisfies your code conside accepting the solution

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with recursion. Jan’s solution has a for loop while I do not see a for loop in yours so I do not know how dat[1,] loops over to the end of the data.

Comment: By the way, I have 500k rows so Jan’s solution with the for loop is taking a very long time to run. Will your solution be faster?

Comment: @Anthony you might night see it since you do not yet know about recursion. 500k. Try running it. And if it throws an error, increase the recursion limit.

Comment: Thank you I have run it and the speed is very fast. However, I have a lot of NA in my data and the code will consider the NA as duplicate and remove rows with NA in it. How do you change the code such that NA will not be considered as duplicate?

Comment: @Anthony. Are you sure itd considering NA as duplicated? Try adding `na.rm =TRUE` after `sum` within tapply. NA cannot be considered as duplicated. But rather no match. Unless  the value next to NA is itself duplicated. In that case you should ask a diffetent question with the example containing NA. Consider visiting my profile page please

Comment: Thank you onyambu but it does not seem to work. I have updated the sample data with NA. It seems your code will result  in “error during wrapup” and cause R to crash. Would you be able to revise your code to handle the updated sample data and give the required result?

Comment: @Anthony you only have 2 NA, include more. Ie include NA that has a duplicate also. Furthermore, the answer given here fullly solves the original post. Changing the post Afterwards makes the answers irrelevant. Consider asking a new question. Someone will help you out.

Comment: @Anthony if you need further help than this, consider shooting an email